# How to update the old jquery libraries used in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, signalr, momentjs

In my ASP.NET MVC project running on .NET 4.7.2, I have used kendo ui, jquery.min.js, jquery.signaturepad.js, moment.js, pdf.js, pdf.worker.js, promise.min.js, jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js. I am using jQuery v1.12.4. Current latest stable version is v3.7.0. Can anyone please suggest how to update the jQuery version from v1.12.4 because it's very old? Do I need to update all the libraries used?

I tried to update the jQuery version. Started from 3.7.0 and then tried 3.6.0, 3.5.0, 3.4.0 and so on but none of them was working. Then finally I tried 2.0.0 it worked but on some of the pages Ajax and other jQuery functions are not working.

Comment: Major releases tend to have breaking changes, ie v1 -> v3 will be unlikely to be fully compatible if you're using anything other than basic core functionality.   You need to read the release notes.  jquery provides a "migration" plugin which will help convert between versions.   Plugins will be expecting a specific version, jquery-migrate *might* help here, but the easiest is to get latest of *all* jquery plugins.  If there's no version of the plugin for your updated jquery, then you'll need a different plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried jquery-migrate but not updated the other jquery plugins pdf-worker, signalR, signaturepad. Can this be the reason that some of the forms are breaking ?
Since its a existing working project , till which version .I can update.